# How to remove all google api related scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

For example, I have many scripts tags in the header from google maps:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/5/common.js
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/5/utils.js
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/5/controls.js
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/5/stats.js
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/26/5/map.js
```

I want to remove these programmatically on demand.

Comment: I guess the best way is u can load the page content first and then load the js or you can use http://requirejs.org

Comment: These are all loaded when you load the main Google Maps API.  Stop doing that, and they'll be removed without needing to try and single them out programmatically (and probably break any map you might have on the page)

Comment: duncan I'm using google auto Complete, I just want them removed when the component using autocomplete unmounts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example 1: how remove script by src contain(in this case we want delete google.js)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Listing 2.2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yahoo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="google.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            if (scripts[i].src.match(/google/)) {
                scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Example 2: how remove by script src ID.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Listing 2.2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" id="script-to-delete" src="yahoo.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="google.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var scriptToDelete = document.getElementById("script-to-delete");
        scriptToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(scriptToDelete);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you

New example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = document.querySelectorAll("script[src*='maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3']");
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        scripts[i].parentNode.removeChild(scripts[i]);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, 

I added new example, with this example all your scripts that contain maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3 will be removed

Comment: Implemented this solution because i  couldn't find anything better.